# signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns Null In Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im trying to add external login functions to my Sever-side blazor.
so far i could login with a google account and it seems to work great so far.
This is how i setup the authentication for google.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options => { /* Authentication options */ })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                // Provide the Google Client ID
                options.ClientId = "{MyClientID}";

                // Provide the Google Client Secret
                options.ClientSecret = "{ClientSecret}";

                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:locale", "locale", "string");
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                {
                    List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                    tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                    {
                        Name = "TicketCreated",
                        Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                    });

                    ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            })
```

My Problem is i dont know if the claims and additional info's are registered (cause there is no trace of them in my database and i can't retrieve them).
I know that i have to get the external user info via SignInManager.
So in my Blazor component i inject the SignManager like this:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
```

then i call the ExternalInfo Like this:

```
 var result= await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

But the result is always null. What do i do wrong? Why is it always null?

A Quick update:
I tested a Razor Page. this works fine on razor pages. so signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
returns null when im calling it from a blazor component.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could use IHttpContextAccessor  instead of using SignInManager to get the user information.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Add HttpContextAccessor service in ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then use it in component:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

 

@inject IHttpContextAccessor accessor

 

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 

Welcome to your new app.

 

<h1>
    @username
</h1>
@code{

 

    public string username;

 

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        username = accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }

 

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That is not what im asking for. The HttpContext gives you only the claims and info about the local user. The user who has logged in with an extrenal account has additional info. such as profile picture or token expiration date. these info comes with the oauth authentication. Your code just gives me the info of the user in the database based on their postback.

Comment: Since the Server-side Blazor uses SignalR under the hood, it will not contains any login related context, the SignInManager and UserManager aren't Razor component concepts. We could only use work around to get the related information when user login and set it into httpcontext, then we could read it from httpcontextaccessor in the blazor component.